# input for loop integers and decimal numbers

Tags: java, input, integer, decimal, average

I should make the input to take different numbers on a new line and find the average, but my program does this only with integers. How can I make the input to take not only integers but numbers like 2.5, 1.25 etc. Please, help me. I know it is simple maybe but I tried different ways and it doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] a=new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Use `double` or `float`?  Why else have you tried?

Comment: use sc.nextFloat() or sc.nextDecimal()

Comment: Reading [The Java™ Tutorials: Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) might help you understand why this doesn't work with integers and what data type is better fitting for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use double instead of it,

```
double[] a=new double[n]
```

Comment: but `sc.nextInt()` always gives you Integer. Original problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

use Double array and take input in double.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   int n = sc.nextInt();
   Double[] a=new Double[n];

   for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
      a[i] = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: I tried this several time and it gives me Incompatible types.
Required:
int
Found:
java.lang.Double

Comment: you have to give double. like you have to enter 25.0 or 25d instead of 25. then it'll work